# How does bison "work": how is it used?

Tags: c++, bison, tokenize

Say I have this C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int monday = 1;
  int tuesday = 2;

  if(monday == tuesday) { fprintf("I should quit my day job"); }

  return 1;
}
```

What would the tokens be?

**What does bison provide me, as a programmer**? Certianly, bison does **not** generate machine code with just a parser grammar? So how do I *interface* with bison? I am not expecting a full answer here, just a pointer to good websites and books.

Comment: For a tokenizer, you should look at [lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29). The mos popular implementation of it today is probably [flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Why does GCC not use `lex`? I'd prefer to roll my own like they did. Just curious what tokens **are** e.g. in my C++ program above.

Comment: You can roll your own, it's actually very easy for simple languages (like for example the old ANSI C standard). For modern variants of C (and especially C++) with all extensions GCC have, it's a lot more work.

Comment: The original gcc avoided lex because the lex of the time was really awful and slow.  The modern `flex` lexers are fast and quite good and would probably serve just fine.  However, C-like languages are hard to tokenize correctly (there's feedback required between the parser and lexer) so the gcc people probably just prefer to stick with their working code.

Comment: Is there any info on what bison actually generates? i.e. What does a parse tree look like? What are the tokens for an example C program? So I can better grasp what the bison tool actually does.

Comment: @unixman83: If you don't know what a parse tree looks like, then you need to read a book or something on parsing. As it stands, this question doesn't even know what it wants to be about: lexing, parsing, both, neither? It's too confused and muddled to be solid.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation on a book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bison implements a generalized LR parser.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html for fairly extensive documentation, with examples.  You don't get back a parse tree per se; instead, you write "actions" that activate on each reduction.  Of course, if your actions simply *build* a parse tree, that will do the trick, if you want to obtain a parse tree.  Modern bison also has a lot of extra tweaking you can insert.

Comment: I have not used that particular book but I know of the author and expect it's pretty good, based on that.  (For whatever that's worth :-) )

Answer (score 3):

The tokens, line by line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

The above line is **not** a C statement, but used by the [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor).

```
int main(void)
```

Five tokens: The keyword `int`, the identifier `main`, the symbol `(`, the keyword `void` and the symbol `)`.

```
{
```

One token: The symbol `{`.

```
int monday = 1;
```

Five tokens: The keyword `int`, the identifier `monday`, the symbol `=`, the integer number `1`, and the symbol `;`.

... And so on

It should also be noted that `=` and `==` are two separate tokens, and that the string is one single token.